# tfs netcore integration tests by testplan - wont find the testcases

Tags: .net-core, tfs, automated-tests, testcase

I have a netcore 6 unit test, which is linked to a tfs test case. In the build pipeline I build the netcore dll contains the test (netcore publish), and publish as an artifact (the bin\Release\net6.0\publish path).
In the release pipeline I copy the artifact files to a temp folder, then apply a Visual Studio Test step on this folder, using Test Plan, selecting test suites containing my test case.
Executing the test release pipeline I see the VS Test step found no tests (dunno what is 'test' - test case or test method):

> Number of testcases discovered : 0

After this line I see

> RunStatistics]This execution slice with id '8405', received '1'
> testcases to execute out of which '0' is discovered.

> 2022-09-07T13:15:26.6593846Z ##[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is
> 'Aborted' because of the error :
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException:
> No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source
> filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria.
> Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter
> criteria is correct.

I use MSTest, the test can be discovered in VS2022 and can be executed correctly.

In the target directory )C:\temp\automata-tfs-tests\MyAPP-autotests) there exists my DLL (Test.AutoTest.dll), also a testhost.exe (if it is interested).

Anyone has any idea what should I do to fix the problem?

Got the following (full) log:

> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0649513Z ##[section]Starting: Test run for Test
> plans 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989252Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989349Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989396Z Description  : Run unit and functional
> tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio
> Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test
> adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests
> using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be
> distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989460Z Version      : 2.153.9
> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989504Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989565Z Help         : [More
> information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
> 2022-09-07T14:16:02.0989612Z
> ============================================================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:03.4309686Z SystemVssConnection exists true
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.4310108Z SystemVssConnection exists true
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.5947964Z SystemVssConnection exists true
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6776898Z In distributed testing flow
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6777031Z
> ====================================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6777567Z Test selector : Test plan
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6777717Z Test plan Id : 5955
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6777832Z Test plan configuration Id : 55
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6777963Z Test suite Id selected: 5956
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6778021Z Test suite Id selected: 5959
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6778071Z Test suite Id selected: 5957
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6778205Z Search folder :
> C:\temp\automata-tfs-tests\MyAPP-autotests
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6779655Z VisualStudio version selected for test
> execution : latest 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6780047Z Attempting to find
> vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.6959999Z Attempting to find vstest.console from a
> visual studio build tools installation. 2022-09-07T14:16:03.7387349Z
> Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.7808933Z Attempting to find vstest.console from a
> visual studio build tools installation. 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8285853Z
> Distributed test execution, number of agents in job : 1
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8286311Z Number of test cases per batch : 100
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8307860Z Run in parallel : false
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8311511Z Run in isolation : false
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8312158Z Path to custom adapters : null
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8322692Z Other console options :
> /UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8400643Z
> ##[warning]Other console options is not supported for this task configuration. This option will be ignored.
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8412667Z Code coverage enabled : false
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.8412905Z Diagnostics enabled : false
> 2022-09-07T14:16:03.9119940Z
> ====================================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:03.9120805Z Source filter: ***test*.dll,!**\obj**
> 2022-09-07T14:16:04.0673691Z SystemVssConnection exists true
> 2022-09-07T14:16:04.0755317Z
> [command]C:\BuildAgent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.153.9\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe
> --inputFile C:\BuildAgent_work_temp\input_9b793c20-2eb7-11ed-955e-6334f9e0a11a.json
> 2022-09-07T14:16:04.1535459Z
> ########################################################################## 2022-09-07T14:16:04.1535614Z DtaExecutionHost version 17.153.29006.1.
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309152Z
> =========================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309447Z AgentName:
> BUILDAGENT-MyBu4-BUILDAGENT-MyBu4-24 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309556Z
> ServiceUrl: http://tfs:8080/tfs/MyBu/ 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309615Z
> TestPlatformVersion: 14.0.25420 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309671Z
> EnvironmentUri: vstest://env/MyAPP/_apis/release/3/764/1759/1
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309725Z QueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 3000
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309821Z MaxQueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds:
> 10000 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1309901Z
> QueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 3000
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1312343Z MaxQueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds:
> 50000 2022-09-07T14:16:05.1312398Z
> =========================================== 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4078702Z TestExecutionHost.Execute: Registered
> TestAgent : 4034 : BUILDAGENT-MyBu4-BUILDAGENT-MyBu4-24
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4371941Z IsValidServiceResponse: Received None
> command..Service Workflow is not active 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4417823Z
> Updated Run Settings: 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4434862Z 
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4435203Z   
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4435273Z
> C:\BuildAgent_work_temp\TR_46cf95a5-fd11-47f6-b503-3fa5ffad22f3 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4435335Z   
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.4435413Z 
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.6424857Z Creating run for selected test plan with
> following parameters 2022-09-07T14:16:05.6426439Z Test plan ID: 5955
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.6427075Z Test suite ID: 5956,5959,5957
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.6427697Z Test configuration ID: 55
> 2022-09-07T14:16:05.7792179Z No test cases for test suite 5956
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0575605Z No test cases for test suite 5957
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0577076Z test configuration mapping:
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0617024Z test settings id : 4895
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0617414Z Run title: MyAPP Auto Test Results
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0617774Z Build location:
> C:\temp\automata-tfs-tests\MyAPP-autotests
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.0618880Z Build Id: 15656
> 2022-09-07T14:16:06.3113960Z Test run with Id 16287 associated
> 2022-09-07T14:16:16.4930577Z Received the command : Start
> 2022-09-07T14:16:16.4949323Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Start
> Command handled 2022-09-07T14:16:16.5604339Z Slice with id = 8407, of
> type = 'Execution' received. 2022-09-07T14:16:16.7663381Z Count of
> test sources found: 1 2022-09-07T14:16:16.7763833Z
> ================================================================= 2022-09-07T14:16:16.7767368Z Discovering tests from sources
> 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4267264Z Number of testcases discovered : 0
> 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4269136Z Discovered tests 0 from sources
> 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4299463Z
> ================================================================= 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4344966Z [RunStatistics]This execution slice with
> id '8407', received '1' testcases to execute out of which '0' is
> discovered. 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4603621Z ##[error]The slice of type
> 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error :
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException:
> No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source
> filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria.
> Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter
> criteria is correct. 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4604497Z    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.Execution.Run(ExecutionStateContext
> stateModdelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2022-09-07T14:16:23.4604635Z    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.ExecutionAndPublish.Run(ExecutionStateContext
> stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> 2022-09-07T14:16:37.5289010Z Received the command : Stop
> 2022-09-07T14:16:37.5289369Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop
> Command handled 2022-09-07T14:16:37.5289442Z SliceFetch Aborted.
> Moving to the TestHostEnd phase 2022-09-07T14:16:37.6567079Z Please
> use this link to analyze the test run :
> http://tfs:8080/tfs/MyBu/MyAPP/_TestManagement/Runs#_a=resultQuery&runId=16287&queryPath=Recent+Run%2FRun16287
> 2022-09-07T14:16:37.6567848Z Test run '16287' is in 'Aborted' state
> with 'Total Tests' : 1 and 'Passed Tests' : 0.
> 2022-09-07T14:16:37.6593787Z ##[error]Test run is aborted. Logging
> details of the run logs. 2022-09-07T14:16:37.6621205Z
> ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task. 2022-09-07T14:16:37.7157795Z
> ########################################################################## 2022-09-07T14:16:37.8420313Z ##[section]Finishing: Test run for Test
> plans

Comment: when I execute "dotnet test Test.AutoTest.dll " on the specific folder, at the end it says: Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: 8 s - Test.AutoTest.dll (net6.0)"

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly (this agent runs automata tests for another project without any problem) now I must add the "Visual Studio test platform installer" also and must change the setting *Test platform version" from "Latest" to "Installed by tools installer". And now it works.